# Sub-scripted value is neither array nor pointer

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, struct

So I am trying to make a simple program which opens up a text file, reads the number of students that the file contains, their first names, last names and student numbers, and stores values in variables, and then finally returns a pointer to an array of those student objects.  My code is as follows: -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
  double studentNumber;
  char *firstName;
  char *lastName;
};

struct student *readStudentRecordFile(char *fileName, int *numOfStudents)
{
int i;
struct student a;

FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(fileName,"r");
fscanf(fp,"%d",&numOfStudents);

for(i=0;i<*numOfStudents;i++)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%s" "%s" "%f", a[i].firstName,a[i].lastName,&a[i].studentNumber);
}

fclose(fp);
}

int main(void)
{

    int nStudents;
    struct student *readArray;

    readArray=readStudentRecordFile("hello.txt", &nStudents);

    return 0;

}
```

The problem is that when I run the program, I get an error stating the sub scripted value is neither an array nor pointer.  I am sort of new to this concept, so I am sort of don't understand what it means.  If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong, and how I can achieve the result that I want, I will be very great-full.  Thank you.

Comment: numOfStudents is already int *. Line should be fscanf(fp,"%d",numOfStudents);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program `a` is neither an array nor a pointer. It is of `struct student` type . You should declare `a` as an array of `struct`.

```
struct student a[SIZE];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a[i].firstName
```

This is array notation.

```
a.firstName
```

This is variable notation.

```
struct student a;
```

This is what you have. It's a variable.

```
struct student a[LEN];
```

This is what you need. It's an array.